# Accessing event.target.elements property in typescript from a form submit event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling

I have the following React code that works ok in JavaScript:

```js
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  console.dir(event.target[0].value)
  console.dir(event.target.usernameInput.value)'EventTarget'.
  console.dir(event.target.elements.usernameInput.value)
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <label htmlFor="usernameInput">Username:</label>
    <input id="usernameInput" type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
[...]
```

I'd like to do the same with TypeScript but I can't access event.target[0], event.target.elements nor event.target.usernameInput, instead I get "Property '0' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'" and "Property 'usernameInput' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'"

This is the ts code:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault()

  console.dir(event.target[0].value) // Property '0' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
  console.dir(event.target.usernameInput.value) // Property 'usernameInput' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
  console.dir(event.target.elements.usernameInput.value) // Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

How can I access any of those properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get a reference to the form in TypeScript, use `currentTarget` instead of `target`:

```
const form = event.currentTarget;
// do stuff with form
// form[0] will be typed as Element, which you can cast to an HTMLInputElement
```

But the better way to examine form values in React would be to use controlled components, and on submit, look at the stateful variable that corresponds to the value:

```
const App = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log(username);
    };
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="usernameInput">Username:</label>
            <input
                id="usernameInput"
                value={username}
                onChange={(e) => { setUsername(e.currentTarget.value); }}
            />
        </form>
    );
};
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the useState approach, just wanted to know the ts equivalent. BTW, event.currentTarget.usernameInput works ok, but event.currentTarget.elements.usernameInput gives me a "Property 'usernameInput' does not exist on type 'HTMLFormControlsCollection'." error